# pyodbc creating corrupt excel file

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to create a new excel file, and the operations seem to execute fine but the resultant xlsx file is corrupt.

I've stripped the code down to this minimal code snippet:

```
import pyodbc

# Setup path and driver connection string 
spreadsheet_path = "C:\\temp\\test_spreadsheet.xlsx"
conn_str = (r'Driver={{Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}};'
            r'DBQ={}; ReadOnly=0').format(spreadsheet_path)

with pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True) as conn:
    # Create table
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "create table sheet1 (COL1 TEXT, COL2 NUMBER);"
    cursor.execute(query)
    cursor.commit()

    # Insert a row
    query = "insert into sheet1 (COL1, COL2) values (?, ?);"
    cursor.execute(query, "apples", 10)
    cursor.commit()

    # Check the row is there
    query = "select * from sheet1;"
    cursor.execute(query)
    for r in cursor.fetchall():
        print(r)

print("done")
```

Note this will create a new spreadsheet in the location specified by spreadsheet_path. I had to use a full path, because the ODBC driver doesn't like relative paths.

I have enabled autocommit, and manually called `cursor.commit()` just to test if it makes a difference, and it does not.

Any ideas?

--

After doing some searching, I found this guide to using the [Excel ODBC driver with PowerShell](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/getting-data-between-excel-and-sql-server-using-odbc/) and it mentions:

> The problem is in the Workbook you create. Whether you name it XLS or
> XSLX it produces an XLSX spreadsheet, in the latest zipped Office Open
> XML form.  The trouble is that, with my version of the driver,  I can
> only get  Excel to read it with the XLS filetype, since it says that
> there is an error if you try to open it as an .XLSX file. I suspect
> that the ODBC driver hasn’t been that well tested by Microsoft.

If I change the file to be .xls, I can open it in excel (although it gives me a warning about the format and extension not matching). The data is valid though. Is this all due to Microsoft's crappy driver? Or is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps try `create table [sheet1$] ...` and `insert into [sheet1$]  ...`

Comment: @GordThompson ```pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] 'sheet1$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long. (-1002) (SQLExecDirectW)")```